# Calculate complete spatial randomness using Python

Tags: python, spatial-statistics

I currently use the csr() function from Splancs for R (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/splancs/splancs.pdf) to calculate complete spatial randomness (CSR) points to be used for spatial statistics. Does anyone perhaps know python code which can create CSR points?

Comment: Depending on what additional software you might be willing to use--QGIS is popular--this question has [many answers here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=random+point+python).

Comment: I'm searching for some more control on what method is used to generate the complete spatial randomness (CSR) points. As far as I know this is a Poisson distribution (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution). So something like: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.poisson.html but then within an arbitrary polygon. I will continue my search ;)

Comment: "More control" in what sense? If you have a specific need not addressed by the related questions, then by all means let's reopen this one.